# Make docker containers accessible via vpn

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, docker

I have three physical machine A, B, C, each of them has docker installed. I want to install openvpn server on machine A, and install openvpn client on B and C. B and C will connect to A. I want to make every docker contanier in A, B, C accessible to any vpn clients connect to A, is this possible? And how?

Typically, vpn server uses 192.168.255.0/24 and docker uses 172.17.42.1/16, should I manually create a bridge that use the vpn adapter for docker?

P.S. If possible, I want the openvpn server on A and vpn clients on B and C also installed inside a docker container.

update:
seems that docker swarm would give some help?